# Reading directory with HTML5 and Chrome FileSystem API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I am trying to display contents of a directory along with `lastModified` property for each item. Unfortunately, to get the property one has to invoke `.file()` method on each entry, which makes the whole loop very problematic. The `console.log` outputs an Array which is reported to have zero items in it, but actually you can expand it and see all the items populated inside.

I was wondering what is the right patern here. Also, tried to find the API for the `entries.sort()` method but could not find any.

The below code is borrowed from an example, adjusted towards my needs.

```
fs.root.getDirectory('recent', {create: true}, function (recentDir) {
  var dirReader = recentDir.createReader();
  var entries = [];

  var readEntries = function () {
    dirReader.readEntries(function (results) {
      if (!results.length) {
        listResults(entries.sort());
      } else {
        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
        readEntries();
      }
    }, fsErrorHandler);
  };

  readEntries();

  function toArray(list) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
  }

  function listResults(entries) {
    var list = [];

    entries.forEach(function (entry, i) {
      entry.file(function (data) {
        list.push(data); // <- async
      });
    });

    console.log(list);
  }
});
```

Comment: I suggest using a promisify library and async/await. https://github.com/kklimuk/filesystem.js/tree/master https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: 1. `entries` is declared as an array so `entries.sort()` is a standard array [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) 2. check if the number of `results` is less than say 1000 and push directly `entries.push.apply(entries, results)` which is much faster and less memory consuming.